# Why can't electrons move in an open circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, batteries

According to answers I saw on net "how electrons flow in a circuit with help of potential difference".

I got answers like:

> A battery is basically just a chemical reaction. At the negative (cathode) end of the battery the reaction releases electrons while at the positive (anode) end of the battery the reaction consumes electrons. As long as the external circuit allows electrons to flow from the cathode to the anode the reaction goes and the battery generates power. [from https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/45284/38738]

According to it, "the cathode of the cell has low positive charges comparatively to the anode which has a high potential (more positive charges) which kind of work as suck in and suck out mechanism for electrons."

[image]

If I open the circuit between, then why can't electrones move? I can agree that electrons in wire the still connected to the cathode side (B) can't move because there is no space so that the negative charge at cathode can push.

Can the electrons in the wire connected to the anode side (A) of battery move? The anode has positive ions which can still suck the electrons from wire part connected to the anode. Up to the time when all positive ions in the anode become neutral or the electrons in the wire side with anode finish (although it is impossible still. Just imagine.)

Why can't electrons move in an open circuit?

Comment: Actually, chemists say that electrons are removed from the cathode and added to the anode. See [here](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-104b-battery-building-blocks), for example, where they write, *"The battery anode is always negative and the cathode positive."*

Comment: Charge can't *continuously* move in an open circuit anymore than water can continuously flow through a pipe that is blocked at one end. It can, however, flow momentarily until the build up of pressure prevents more water from entering or the accumulated charge of the electrons repel other electrons from entering.

Comment: Anode is negative and cathode is positive.

Comment: The answer that you read has the words "anode" and "cathode" backwards. By convention, the word "anode" refers to the **negative** terminal of a battery and the word "cathode" refers to the **positive** terminal. (In my opinion, it's best to never use the words "anode" and "cathode" when talking about a battery, and to always say "positive terminal" and "negative terminal" instead.) I recommend editing your question by replacing "anode" with "positive terminal" and "cathode" with "negative terminal" everywhere.

Comment: "*Why can't electrons move in an open circuit?*" If they could the battery would be flat before it got from the factory to the shop.

Comment: _"Why can't electrons move in an open circuit?"_ - where would they move to?

Comment: Electrons do move under an open circuit, but the movement is random; there is no drift in any particular direction that would amount to a current.

Answer (score 7):

> I can agree that electrons in wire's side still connected to cathode side(B) can't kove because there is no space so that negative charge at cathode can push.

This applies an overly simplified understanding of [electrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics) which is sufficiently simplified to become inaccurate. As soon as a small number of excess electrons are on the wire connected to the anode (not cathode), there is a net [electric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field) that serves to repel further electrons from traveling into and down the wire. As soon as the [electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Electrostatics) \$\int{\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}}\$ associated with this field is comparable to the battery's voltage, the battery cannot do enough work to send further electrons.

Furthermore, electrons do not leave the wire into thin air because the battery does not give them enough energy to overcome the metal's [workfunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function).

> But the electron in wire connected with anode side(A) of battery can move? Aren't they? As anode have positive ions which can still suck the electrons from wire part connected to anode

Yes, some small number of electrons still moves into the battery (at the cathode), until the electric field caused by net positive charges attracts electrons so strongly that the battery cannot provide further net current. Same principle as on the cathode side.

You may consider the entire scenario as a battery connected to a small capacitance:

[image]

Comment: "Yes, some small number of electrons still moves into the battery (at the cathode)" why u write cathode sir ? I Mean cathode already have more negative charges (low potential)? I mean i have learnt as ' anife has posotive charges or ions that attracts electron and cathide has negative charge that repels electron"  is it wrong? Other way round?

Comment: "As soon as a small number of excess electrons are on the wire connected to the anode (not cathode)" how can anode wire get negative charge in open circuit ? Even it should get positive charge as anode of battery should suck electrons from wire connected to it??!! (Acc. To my understanding)

Comment: @SureshChandraPal You have the two terminals backwards. At the anode, the electrochemical reaction yields electrons to the outside circuit during discharge.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the electrons in the wire connected to the [positive] side (A) of battery move? The [positive side] has positive ions which can still suck the electrons from wire part connected to the [positive side]. Up to the time when all positive ions in the [positive side] become neutral or the electrons in the wire [attached to the positive side run out]  (although it is impossible still. Just imagine.)

It's because of the fact that protons attract electrons, and electrons repel electrons.

It's true that the wire has some electrons that it's capable of giving up, and the battery has some positive ions. However, after the battery has "sucked up" just a few electrons from the wire, the battery will end up having more electrons than protons, or the wire will end up having more protons than electrons, or both.

If the battery has more electrons than protons, then those electrons will repel other electrons, which will eventually stop the flow of electrons into the battery. Likewise, if the wire has more protons than electrons, then those protons will attract electrons, which will eventually stop the flow of electrons out of the wire.

When we think about batteries and wires in terms of protons and electrons, everything can get pretty complicated. Fortunately, Kirchhoff's circuit laws give us a much easier way to analyze circuits like these. According to Kirchhoff's laws, the answer is much simpler: "No electrons flow out of the end of the wire connected to the battery because no electrons flow into the other end of the wire."

Answer (score 0):

There is a very special case where electrons move in an open circuit, the famous Oxford Electric Bell.

[image]

[Source](https://archwww.physics.ox.ac.uk/history/Exhibit1.html)

> It consists of two voltaic "dry-piles", covered with an insulating
> layer of sulphur, connected in series and, at their lower ends, to two
> bells. Between the bells is suspended a metal sphere about 4mm in
> diameter which is attracted alternately by the bells and transfers
> charge from one to the other. The frequency of its oscillation is
> about 2Hz; so far the bells have been rung of the order of 10 billion
> times.

There is no continuos current flowing, only for the short time when the suspended sphere touches one of the bells.

The white cylinders are high voltage batteries with a very high internal resistance. The electrons are transported by the moving sphere. One bell is connect to the negative contact of a battery, the other bell to the positive contact of the other battery.